# В чем ошибка? Index out of bounds for length

Tags: java

```
class ex3{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] d={1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] b= new int[d.length];
    int g=d.length;
    int f=0;
    while(g>0){
        b[f]=d[g];
        g--;
        f++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<g;i++ ) {
        System.out.print(b[i]);
    }
}
```

}

В чем ошибка? Компилятор выдает Index 5 out of bounds for length 5 at ex3.main(ex3.java:8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первой итерации `while` Вы залезаете за границу `d` - когда `g` равно `d.length`.

```
while (g > 0) {
  b[f++] = d[--g];
}
for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
  System.out.print(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, а в чем проблема моего кода? по сути тоже самое что и у вас, кроме условия в цикле for(ошибку понял:)).

Comment: @bazmexes обратите внимание на пре-декремент `--g`

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что в java элементы массива нумеруются, начиная с нуля. Таким образом индекс элемента находится в промежутке `[0, length-1]`

Вы же пытаетесь использовать индекс равный длине массива `int g=d.length;`
Нужно либо `int g=d.length-1;` и исправить `while (g >= 0)`, либо `b[f]=d[g-1];`.